Fence posts on concrete slab
I have a concrete slab of about 1.5m wide and 5m long. I want to put a solid colorond fence (light green) near the middle of the slab, along the long side. The fence is about 1.8-2m high, 4m long. There will also be an aluminium gate (dark green) to finish that 5m section.
The slab is 10cm thick.
Is it safe to use post bases like the one in the attached photo? I'm thinking of having 3 posts (blue).
Thanks.



It sounds like both sides of the fence would be quite tiny to move/walk through.  ~2 feet/0.75m is not that big, are you sure you want it that small?

Is the fence a straight run, or are there corners anywhere?

@crip659 the slab is already there, and next to the it are paved areas, so walking space is not an issue.

High wind would be a concern with those post bases.

@AloysiusDefenestrate the new fence is straight. However, it will be connected perpendicularly to an existing fence. Both fence are solid, so the sails efect is high. I'm trying to add a diagram to the post.

@crip659 yes, my main concern is with the lateral winds

Are you willing to dig through the concrete for a legitimately good post anchor beside the gate? (I'm assuming here that you can tie in to the existing fence in a sturdy fashion.) As it is, you have very little slab thickness to anchor to, and a problematic design (tall, long, straight).

As the slab is 100mm thick, I'm a bit worried about how to DIY (do it myself). I'll attach the right hand side to the existing fence.

How strong do the fence posts need to be?  You could drill holes and epoxy anchor bolts into the slab.

@Huesmann that is part of my question. I don't know how strong they should be

Is your fence going to be solid, or slatted?
